jenkins variable between scripts
I have a problem with vars in jenkinsfile.
I want to pass variable between scripts but i dont get a right output.
for example:

node ('main') {
        def varpwd = ''

        stage('stage1') {
            varpwd = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''
                #!/bin/bash
                set -e
                set +x
                pwd
            ''').trim()
        }
        stage('stage2'){
                echo varpwd
                status = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """
                    echo $varpwd
                """)
        }
}

from that code I get something like this:
echo /home/user
/home/user

echo Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...

What I dont understand is this "Reading package lists..."
It doesnt make any sense to me.

it doesnt recognize it because it search $varpwd in the script which it doesnt have.

Are you sure? I just ran your code and it outputs: ```15:37:46  [Pipeline] echo
15:37:46  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/scoping/var
15:37:46  [Pipeline] sh
15:37:47  + echo /var/jenkins_home/workspace/scoping/var


Ok I got the problem. I installed in the start to the first script jq package and for some reason it exeuted it in the end of the script and not in the start. So I got its output and not the echo one.
